# How to URL Encode Page Item Correctly - APEX 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a `RESET_PSWD` button on a Form that calls a dynamic action with 4 true actions defined.

1. `Confirm` Action
2. `Execute Server-side Code` - PL/SQL procedure to generate new temp pswd
3. `Execute Server-side Code` - PL/SQL procedure to generate modal url using `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL`
4. `Execute JavaScript Code` - use url from step 3 to open modal

The goal of the DA is to generate a Temp Password, build a URL to the modal (passing in the new Temp Password from Step 2), and then navigate to the modal. Between `Step 2` and `Step 3` the value in `P7_TEMP_PSWD` is getting truncated due to special characters not being url encoded correctly between the request calls.

```
-- package procedure to get & set url for confirmation modal (Step 3)
PROCEDURE get_feedback_url (
  p_username   VARCHAR2,
  p_temp_pswd  VARCHAR2
) IS

  vcPswdEncoded  VARCHAR2(1000);
  vcURL          VARCHAR2(1000);
  vcValueList    VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

  vcPswdEncoded := APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE(p_temp_pswd);
  vcValueList   := p_username ||','|| vcPswdEncoded;

  vcURL := APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page   => '12',
                              p_items  => 'P12_USERNAME,P12_TEMP_PSWD',
                              p_values => vcValueList,
                              p_plain_url => TRUE);

  APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P7_FEEDBACK_URL', vcURL);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    csa.rsn_logger.log_error(p_rsn_app => 'RSNUM',
                              p_app_loc => 'rsnum_user.get_feedback_url',
                              p_log_msg => SQLERRM);
END;
```

I am trying to url encode the temp pswd before building the url, but I am getting the following results:

[image]

The value after using `APEX_UTIL.ENCODE_URL` is what I want, but it seems like `APEX_PAGE.GET_URL` is also encoding the values so '%' is encoded again. Is there a way to opt out of `GET_URL` doing this? The reason why I am using `ENCODE_URL` in the first place is because APEX does was not encode '#' (and a few other characters) by default and that was causing me problems originally.

Comment: Even if it is only a temporary password, I would strongly advise against using it in an url, especially if it is not encrypted. You could try to save it in a special column of your users database table, and use a pre-header-process on your target page to load it. This way, you also solve your encoding problem.

Comment: Good point. Our applications are on a locked down intranet (not public facing), but you are right to keep security in mind regardless. I also thought about making it an APPLICATION ITEM this way do not need to pass it around between pages, but I may try your idea instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wish there was a better way to do this, but figured out a working solution (will need to test edge cases, but seems to work). I created a Before Header computation on the modal page with the following expression:

```
UTL_URL.UNESCAPE(:P12_TEMP_PSWD)
```